# ClGetPlatformIDs hang

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I am trying to run OpenCL app on a NVIDIA P1000 GPU. A sample application that gets the number of openCL platforms and the devices found by each platform works fine. When I try to run the OpenCL code from my application, the app hangs on ClGetPlatformIDs

```
Thread 17 (Thread 0x7f189af86700 (LWP 15786)):
#0  0x00007f18e53f7b57 in munmap () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f18e538654a in __GI__IO_setb () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f18e5384e90 in __GI__IO_file_close_it () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f18e53798b0 in fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f1898c5fb02 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#5  0x00007f1898c6165e in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#6  0x00007f1898d5029f in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#7  0x00007f1898c52530 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#8  0x00007f1898c5c176 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#9  0x00007f1898d2fab3 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#10 0x00007f1898d2fe66 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#11 0x00007f1898c43a68 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#12 0x00007f1898c2d045 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#13 0x00007f1898b128cd in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#14 0x00007f1898b127c8 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
#15 0x00007f189af896a3 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libOpenCL.so.1
#16 0x00007f189af8b8cc in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libOpenCL.so.1
#17 0x00007f18e6161bf3 in __pthread_once_slow () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#18 0x00007f189af89c71 in clGetPlatformIDs () from /usr/lib64/libOpenCL.so.1
```

I am not clear of the reason of why the openCL call hangs. Same app on a different machine with NVIDIA RTX5000 works fine. What are the possible root causes of ClGetPlatformIDs hang?

Comment: Hanging in `munmap` means it's stuck somewhere in the kernel. This is likely a driver bug.

Comment: Could you show us the code that triggers this?

Comment: ClGetPlatformIDs call works fine without any issues when run in a simple standalone code. If there is a driver bug, even the call in the standalone code also should not work, right?  My main application spawns a process and in that process, we run the OpenCL app where I am calling the ClGetPlatformIDs. The process hangs in that call.

Comment: Can ClGetPlatformIDs fail if we have two incompatible GPUs on the system? Currently we have P1000 and P620 on Z8G4.